# Architecture design for a web application that runs SSH connections to remote servers

Tags: web-development, architecture, django, web-servers

This is a followup to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066797/using-a-library-which-uses-threads-and-subprocess-from-a-django-website/19073102?noredirect=1#19073102).

I have to make a web GUI for [a library](http://saga-project.github.io/saga-python/) that manages remote clusters via SSH.

The main point is that this library spawns threads and subprocesses (Popen) internally (for the SSH connections), so I think I am I/O bound by these SSH connections. I want to prevent my server from going down as soon as I get 20-50 simultaneous requests.

I have no idea of how to proceed with the architecture. I don't know if I can solve this at the server level with a more powerful server (gevent??) or if I should do something like using background threads (twisted reactor??)

Some considerations:

- I work with django so the server (if I finally have only one) must be WSGI.
- I need both blocking and non-blocking calls via SSH.
- I will probably need shared state between successive requests as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really want to be looking at separating the concerns here -- have your web app make requests to a message queue, have the execution components process messages from the queue. This also makes security much less nightmarish because you can push the things manging SSH tasks well off the web tier.

The original answer [above] was a bit terse and didn't answer a few questions.

- How will this avoid SSH connection threads exhausting the server? It will avoid it because you can easily throttle most message queues to avoid that. And you can easily ad back-end workers if you are exhausing your initial setup without material change in your application.
- How can I have shared state between requests? The same way you would normally -- you send the request out to the queue, it completes and brings data back which can be passed to the next request.
- How would it appear to users? Could there be status updates? In most cases you can get the data out of the queuing system, or at least have status updates for task completion. Most message queues can easily give indication of failures or failures to start as well.
- Would I have to block the process when communicating between my web server in the message queue be blocking? Not unless you wrote it that way. You can easily setup an ajax request to tickle the queue every few seconds for status on a message to update the UI.
- Is this over-engineering? Not unless you decide to roll your own message queue.

Comment: That will make for a better design, but it won't solve the "main point": the SSH connection threads exhausting the server. If I move the connections to another process I would still have to connect with such process for my blocking calls (those calls where I need the result for my http response)

Comment: @Adrián I suspect you misunderstand the answer. You should pass these requests to a message queue, and a completely separate process will receive them from the queue and actually do the work of making the ssh connections and collecting the job results. The user will then come back later to check on the status of their job; you do not keep their HTTP request open until it finishes.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @MichaelHampton . That is actually something I've been considering (celery). But the purpose of my web is to start the jobs in some actual job queues (those accessed via SSH). So if I do this I would have a "queue of remote job queue requests". I'm not sure if that makes sense, it seems a bit over-engeenered to me. Also, with this solution I wouldn't be able to anwser back to the browser something like "Your job has been successfully submited to xxx.xxx.xxx (some IP)" while being really sure that the job has been indeed received. What do you think about this?

Comment: Yes, you would be able to get that back; a message queue can support bidirectional communication.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know that, but I would have to block waiting for the other process to handle the message in the queue (and to handle it, this process will have to wait for a response via SSH). That is what I mean in my first comment to Wyatt's answer

Comment: @Adrián -- no, you don't have to block anything -- you just need to work out how to update folks appropriately. Will try and update the answer quite a bit given the subsequent questions.

Comment: Updated the answer to be a bit more clear on @Adrián 's questions.

Comment: I haven't found any alternative that would allow me to skip the AJAX polling, so I will finally do as you say, with celery. Thanks for the more in-depth explanation.